# Python CSV DictReader/Writer issues

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to extract a bunch of lines from a CSV file and write them into another, but I'm having some problems.

```
import csv

f = open("my_csv_file.csv", "r")
r = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
fieldnames = r.fieldnames

target = open("united.csv", 'w')
w = csv.DictWriter(united, fieldnames=fieldnames)

while True:
try:
    row = r.next()
    if r.line_num <= 2: #first two rows don't matter
        continue
    else:
        w.writerow(row)

except StopIteration:
    break

f.close()
target.close()
```

Running this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "unify.py", line 16, in <module>
    w.writerow(row)
File "C:\Program Files\Python25\lib\csv.py", line 12
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(row
File "C:\Program Files\Python25\lib\csv.py", line 12
    if k not in self.fieldnames:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Not entirely sure what I'm dong wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know either, but since all you're doing is copying lines from one file to another why are you bothering with the `csv` stuff at all? Why not something like:

```
f = open("my_csv_file.csv", "r")
target = open("united.csv", 'w')

f.readline()
f.readline()
for line in f:
    target.write(line)
```

Comment: Brilliant.  I do tend to overcomplicate things.  Thanks.

Comment: This answer is brilliant, because it addresses the underlying problem ;)

Answer (score 13):

To clear up the confusion about the error: you get it because `r.fieldnames` is only set once you read from the input file for the first time using `r`. Hence the way you wrote it, `fieldnames` will always be initialized to `None`.

You may initialize `w = csv.DictWriter(united, fieldnames=fieldnames)` with `r.fieldnames` only after you read the first line from `r`, which means you would have to restructure your code.

This behavior is documented in the [Python Standard Library documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.fieldnames)

> DictReader objects have the following public attribute:
>
> csvreader.fieldnames
>
> If not passed as a parameter when creating the object, this attribute is initialized upon first access or when the first record is read from the file.

Answer (score 1):

As for the exception, looks like this line:

```
w = csv.DictWriter(united, fieldnames=fieldnames)
```

should be

```
w = csv.DictWriter(target, fieldnames=fieldnames)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the error is most likely that your original CSV file (my_csv_file.csv) doesn't have a header row. Therefore, when you construct the reader object, its fieldnames field is set to `None`.

When you try to write a row using the writer, it first checks to make sure there are no keys in the dict that are not in its list of known fields. Since `fieldnames` is set to `None`, an attempt to dereference the key name throws an exception.