# AttributeError when trying to use seek() to get last row of csv file

Tags: python, csv, seek

I am trying to return the last row from a csv file.  I am modifying another function that I wrote previously that returns the last line from a text file.  It seemed to work as expected at first, but now when I call the function it throws an error.

```
reader.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
```

```
AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

---

```
import os
import csv
def getLastFile(filename):
    distance = 1024
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        reader.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        if reader.tell() < distance:
            reader.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
            lines = reader.readlines()
            lastline = lines[-1]
        else:
            reader.seek(-1 * distance, os.SEEK_END)
            lines = reader.readlines()
            lastline = lines[-1]

    return lastline
```

Can someone please help me modify my code?  I was pretty sure you could use seek in this way, maybe I'm mistaken?

Comment: Could you give us the csv file to work with too?

Comment: You can `seek` and `tell` on `file` objects, but not on `csv.reader` objects as far as I can tell. I'm not sure there is a good way to do this in conjunction with `csv.reader`.

Comment: I just made a small .csv file with 20 or so rows and 5 columns filled with random numbers.  The code (I believe) should work with a generic .csv file, returning the last row, so I'm not sure it would help if I posted it, but I could if you want.  Thanks!

Comment: Darn, that's frustrating!

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - the target refers to "How do I tell I'm on the last line" - this question is "How do I get the last line"... they're not synonymous...

Comment: Thank you Joe I appreciate your comment

Comment: Thetravellingfool: I too think **Jon** is correct and have voted to reopen—not that it matters much and even though it's now years later. `;-)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a slight variation of the core concept in the accepted answer to the question [Have csv.reader tell when it is on the last line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970983/have-csv-reader-tell-when-it-is-on-the-last-line) applied to your variation of the problem. Since each row is potentially a different length, there's really no way around having to read the whole file.

```
import csv

def get_last_row(csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename, 'r') as f:
        lastrow = None
        for lastrow in csv.reader(f): pass
        return lastrow
```

**Update**

Here's a simpler and likely faster way to do it using a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque). I got the idea from one of the answers to the question [How to read an output line containing a list of integers produced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377965/how-to-read-an-output-line-containing-a-list-of-integers-produced).

```
from collections import deque
import csv

def get_last_row(csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename, 'r') as f:
        try:
            lastrow = deque(csv.reader(f), 1)[0]
        except IndexError:  # empty file
            lastrow = None
        return lastrow
```

Answer (score 0):

csv reader not support seek, so you can get csv file last line as text file, then process last line as csv.
In your code, if last line length > distance, then will get only part of last line.

```
import os

def get_last_line(fin):
    line_len = 80
    fin.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    file_size = fin.tell()
    while True:
        line_len = min(line_len * 2, file_size)
        fin.seek(-line_len, os.SEEK_END)
        lines = f.readlines()
        if len(lines) > 1 or line_len == file_size:
            return lines[-1]
```

then read csv:

```
import csv

print ', '.join(csv.reader([last_line]).next())
```