# How to read an output line containing a list of integers produced

Tags: python, file, list

In my penultimate (next to last) line from all the files in a specific directory, I have a list of integers like this:

```
[142356, 12436546, 131434645, 56464]
```

I would like to read this penultimate line from all the files from that specific directory, and using it again as a list in my new python script containing the same values, of course. So I will be able to process again these lists.

All the text filenames start by "chr" and finish by ".txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following - `iglob` to match the filenames, `literal_eval` to parse the data as a list, and a `deque` to efficiently get the last two lines of a file:

```
from collections import deque
from glob import iglob
import ast

def get_lists(pattern):
    for filename in iglob(pattern):
        with open(filename) as fin:
            penultimate = deque(fin, 2)[0]
            yield ast.literal_eval(penultimate)

data = list(get_lists('chr*.txt'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and [glob.glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```
import ast
import glob
print([ast.literal_eval(open(filename).readlines()[-1]) for filename in [("desired_directory/chr*.txt"])
```