# Find first and last occurrence in CSV by day-time

Tags: python, csv, datetime, filtering

Want to find out first occurrence and last occurrence of the value from the row from the csv file using python. The value which I want to compare is date value which is row[1].

Input:

```
ABC, 12/2/2017 ,9:21 AM
ABC, 12/2/2017 ,1:15 PM
ABC, 12/2/2017 ,6:38 PM
ABC, 12/4/2017 ,9:21 AM
ABC, 12/4/2017 ,1:01 PM
ABC, 12/7/2017 ,11:59 AM
ABC, 12/8/2017 ,9:33 AM
ABC, 12/8/2017 ,11:15 AM
ABC, 12/8/2017 ,5:15 PM
```

Output:

```
ABC, 12/2/2017 ,9:21 AM
ABC, 12/2/2017 ,6:38 PM
ABC, 12/4/2017 ,9:21 AM
ABC, 12/4/2017 ,1:01 PM
ABC, 12/7/2017 ,11:59 AM
ABC, 12/8/2017 ,9:33 AM
ABC, 12/8/2017 ,5:15 PM
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296955/attributeerror-when-trying-to-use-seek-to-get-last-row-of-csv-file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Is your data already sorted like your Input Example ?

Comment: The question is not clear. The first row will be row[0] and not row[1]. Explain what you want to do clearly and also what code have you tried till now.

Comment: @NikosTavoularis If you label the given link (find last row of csv file), it would be clear that this does not answer the question for content-filtering ( _last timestamp_  ) 

Answer (score 0):

This presumes your data is already sorted as in your example.  `operator.itemgetter(1)` returns a function that allows `itertools.groupby` to group rows on the 2nd item (i.e. `row[1]`).

```
import iterools
import operator
import csv

with open('some.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    result = []
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(reader, operator.itemgetter(1)):
        group = list(g)
        result.append(group[0])
        if len(group) > 1:
            result.append(group[-1])
```

Comment: This is a strong _presumption_ on ❗(semantically) sorted rows, but will achieve questioned filtering: last row per day-group == latest day-time 

Answer (score 0):

Helping you to express your problem:

- helps you to ask clearly, which in turn
- enables you to write pseudo-code, which in turn
- can be the minimal example (what you tried already), which in turn
- should be posted by you in the question, which in turn
- enables us to guide you to the solution

---

#### Problem

Find the first and last occurrence (time within a day) as row of the given CSV file.
The program needs to be coded in **Python**.
The program needs to **read rows** from the CSV file.
I want to read each row **splitted into 3 columns** (especially second column *date* and third column *time*) in order to **compare their values** to respective values of other rows.
The comparison should happen within a *date* **group** and only compare rows of the same date.

date value which is row[1].

#### Given Input

A simple example of the CSV file has following 3 rows which represent a single day (second column with value `12/2/2017`) with 3 times (third column with 3 distinct values `9:21 AM`, `1:15 PM` and `6:38 PM`):

```
ABC, 12/2/2017 ,9:21 AM
ABC, 12/2/2017 ,1:15 PM
ABC, 12/2/2017 ,6:38 PM
```

#### Pseudo code

Supposed I don't know python and have no clue where to start with coding, here is the logical flow I would like to program in python:

1. read all rows of the CSV file
2. group the rows by second column (date) values to a list of times within a single day
3. compare the list of times (grouped per day) by third column (time) values to filter only 2 rows into the result: the first occurrence (earliest time) and the last occurrence (latest time)
4. write the filtered result as rows to the CSV output file

#### Expected Output

After this the expected output CSV would contain:

```
ABC, 12/2/2017 ,9:21 AM

ABC, 12/2/2017 ,6:38 PM
```

Note that one row has been filtered-out (removed from result):

```
ABC, 12/2/2017 ,1:15 PM
```