# Reading 2nd column of last row in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to make a money counter whereby you can add money and remove money and just track where your money is going (this is just a mini project for me, I am aware there are much better apps suited for this).

I would like to present the current balance every time the program is run, my only problem is how I can read the last row in the csv file and the second column in it.

This is my csv file layout:

`Date, Current Balance, Money In, Money Out, Reason, Other`
`10/04/1994, £205, £10, -, Birthday, -`

My current code is:

```
with open("Logs.csv", "r") as f:
    for row[-1] in f:
        currentBalance = row[-1], row[-2]


def MainMenu():
    print(f"{bnum1} Welcome to your Money Logger! {bnum1}\n\
{bnum2} 1.         Money In           {bnum2}\n\
{bnum2} 2.         Money Out          {bnum2}\n\
{bnum3} ")
```

I'm quite new to programming so i'm not really sure how to go about fetching a specific column and row. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not super fast, but:

```
with open('Logs.csv', 'r') as logs:
    data = logs.readlines()
    last_row = data[-1].split('\t') # Update for tab delimit.
    second_cell = last_row[1]
```

You open the file, then use `readlines()` to read all of the data back 
into a list. That is, you have an item in the list for each line. Then
access the last element - `data[-1]`, and split that into a list with 
`split(',')`. You may need to use a space after the comma, just play 
about with it. Last, you grab the second element from that list. 
Remember python uses 0 based indexes.

Let me know if you have questions. Good luck.

Edit: Updated with tab delimit per @martineau

Comment: So this is my current code after adding your code: codeshare.io/5QLp6q. The problem is, I'm getting a index error: line 14, in <module> second_cell = last_row[1] IndexError: list index out of range. Any ideas how to fix this?, Thanks for everything

Comment: I suspect @martineau is correct. If you can show me what's in the line that fails, I can help.

Comment: line 15 in your variation but in Martineau it's the same error but different line.

Comment: Updated with @martineau's comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) to handle a table/dataframe. You could use something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Logs.csv')
print(df.iloc[:, 1]) # print the second column
print(df.iloc[1, :]) # print the second row
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I feel like pandas is quite a complicated module in general for beginners like me. But thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the update to my answer to the question [AttributeError when trying to use seek() to get last row of csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20297182/355230).

```
from collections import deque
import csv

def get_last_row(csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
        try:
            lastrow = deque(csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'), 1)[0]
        except IndexError:  # Empty file.
            lastrow = None
        return lastrow


row = get_last_row("Logs.csv")
print(row[1])  # Print second column. -> £205
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm getting an index error for this code: https://codeshare.io/anMZrV.
line 30, in <module>
    print(row[1])  # Print second column. -> £205
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: DeathResister: Sounds like the last row doesn't have a second column. Put a `print(row)` before the `print(row[1])`and see what's in it.

Comment: It prints this out "['10/04/1994\t£205\t£10\t-\tBirthday\t-']"

Comment: @DeathResister: Oh...it's because your csv file is tab- not  comma-delimited — which isn't obvious from the csv file layout posted in your question, See update to my answer.